# Not able to login in Facebook by adding Fragment over Activity in Facebook SDK 3.20.0?

Tags: android, facebook

I've been able to login to facebook if I write login code in MainActivity instead of loading fragment over it. I'm not able to login when I add MainFragment to MainActivity.

Below is MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, new MainFragment())
    .commit();

    }

}
```

Below is MainFragment -

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

private LoginButton btnlogin; 
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private TextView txtUserName;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("Frag", "oncreate called...");

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e("Frag", "oncreateView called...");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_activity_layout, null);
    txtUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    btnlogin = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    btnlogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

    btnlogin.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {
                txtUserName.setText("welcome " + user.getName());
            } else {
                txtUserName.setText("not logged in.");
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}


private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

        Log.e("Frag", "statusCallback called...");

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Frag", "onResume called...");
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("Frag", "onPause called...");
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Frag", "onDestroy called...");
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("Frag", "onActivityResult called...");
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    Log.e("Frag", "onSavedInstance called...");
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call setFragment on your login button:

```
btnlogin.setFragment(this);
```

If you don't do the above, then it will use the activity to call `startActivityForResult` during login, which means the `onActivityResult` will also go to your activity. If you set the Fragment, it will use the Fragment to call `startActivityForResult`, which means the `onActivityResult` will go to your Fragment.